# Javascript controllers new audio tag

Tags: javascript

So I have the javascript code working so it plays the first file then second. However the issue is I now can't pause the second file without the first file replying?

I am wondering how do you correctly set controllers to the following code

```
 var audio = new Audio("FILE 1");
          audio.play();
          audio.addEventListener('ended',function(){
               audio.id = "stream";
               audio.src = "FILE2";
               audio.load();
               audio.play();
               //alert("it should be playing");
         });
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you add `ended` event to audio. So when the file ("FILE 1" or "FILE 2") in audio ends, it will load and play "FILE 2". You must change your code to create new `Audio` object for "FILE 2".

```
 var audio = new Audio("FILE 1");
          audio.play();
          audio.addEventListener('ended',function(){
               audio = new Audio("FILE 2");
               audio.id = "stream";
               audio.load();
               audio.play();
               //alert("it should be playing");
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end I went with the following solution

Javascript code

```
var aud = document.getElementById("player");
       aud.onended = function() {
        document.getElementById("player").setAttribute('src', 'ADVERT.mp3');
        document.getElementById("player").play();
            var advert = document.getElementById("player");
            advert.onended = function() {     
              document.getElementById("player").setAttribute('src', 'EndOfAdvert.mp3');
              document.getElementById("player").play();
                var stationStream = document.getElementById("player");
                stationStream.onended = function() {  
                  document.getElementById("player").setAttribute('src', 'STREAM URL');
                  document.getElementById("player").play();
                };
              };
      };
```

HTML

```
<audio id="player">
                <source 
                    src="StartOfAdvert.mp3"
                    type="audio/mpeg"
                />
            </audio>
```